# Not able to run the maven jar with httpclient dependency

Tags: java, maven, apache-httpclient-4.x

Created the jar file using maven, when i try to execute java -jar  getting below exception :

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `HttpUriRequest` is in your jar. Most likely you need to create executable jar using Maven [shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or [assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) plugins.

Comment: adding maven shade plugin resolves the above mentioned exception, thanks a lot ! :)